# Why does puppet keeps telling me: "Puppet.features.rubygems? is deprecated. Require rubygems in your application's entry point if you need it"?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

I've got a reasonably small (~10 hosts) puppet installation, and recently, I've started to get warning messages on every puppet agent run. The message is:

```
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/stdlib/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/firewall/lib/facter/iptables.rb
Info: Loading facts in /etc/puppet/modules/concat/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/root_home.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/concat_basedir.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/facter_dot_d.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/iptables.rb
Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/puppet_vardir.rb
Debug: catalog supports formats: b64_zlib_yaml dot pson raw yaml; using pson
Warning: Puppet.features.rubygems? is deprecated. Require rubygems in your application's entry point if you need it.
   (at /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/puppet/util/feature.rb:17:in `add')
Info: Caching catalog for hostname.example.com
```

I'm not 100% sure what changed - this is only a test environment, so we're not quite as strict about change management as we should be. It could be that a new puppet package was installed, or an extra module added - we don't know.

The problem is, I've no information to go on regarding what could be causing this. Grepping through my `/etc/puppet/modules` folder reveals a bunch of modules that use rubygems.

What's causing this warning, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [by design](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/16757) as of Puppet 3.0.1.

> If bundler is loaded, e.g. bundler exec puppet, then don’t load
>   rubygems, since bundler has its own logic for managing gems in the
>   current application environment. And the set of gems, versions, etc is
>   often different than what gems you may have installed, via rvm for
>   example.
>
> If bundler is not loaded, fall back on the old behavior, which is to
>   ensure rubygems is loaded before calling any puppet code. Ideally,
>   this should be done in the bin/puppet script, however, that doesn’t
>   work for rack setups, so we moved rubygems loading to the command line
>   code, which is effectively the puppet application entry point.
>
> Several features, e.g. stomp, were calling Puppet.features.rubygems?
>   only for its side-effect of loading rubygems before evaluating the
>   calling feature’s gems. This is no longer necessary now that we ensure
>   the gem loading system is sane early on.
>
> Custom features may be calling Puppet.features.rubygems?, so we’ve
>   added a deprecation warning and preserved the old behavior (of
>   explicitly requiring rubygems). It may be necessary to modify custom
>   features in order to ensure puppet works correctly in a bundler
>   environment.

If you've updated your puppetmaster to 3.0.1, you should update all your puppet agents as well. Or vice-versa.

Comment: I'm on puppet deb 3.1.0-1puppetlabs1 for both master and all clients and have been since first install. I'm confused as to why this has just started happening...

Comment: Bug in something? Explore with `grep -R` perhaps?

Comment: I eventually narrowed this down to an errant few lines in the `sensu` puppet module. I've filed a bug on github: https://github.com/sensu/sensu-puppet/issues/23

Answer (score 1):

if any of the provider or anything else you are using which calls Puppet.features.rubygems? then this warning is shown. In past puppet used to load ruby gems inside libraries which was not the right way and was supposed to be deprecated. But to maintain the backward compatibility they have still kept this call alive and show a warning to indicate that this is not the right way.

Comment: So, given that this warning only just started appearing, how do I track down where it's being called?